# Passing entry_ids to channel:entries. Pull data from channel

Tags: expressionengine

I've channel resources - with Title, Thumbnail, and fluid field resource_asset.

I'm creating the low_variable with entry_select which is returning the ids.

How to get data from the resources fields? This is my code. For example, I want to display the Titles:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="resources" entry_id="{lv_resources}"}
    <h2>title</h2>
{/exp:channel:entries }
```

Comment: You could try this:
{exp:channel:entries fixed_order="{lv_resources}" dynamic="no"}
<h2>title</h2>
{/exp:channel:entries}
Also: is the Low Variable set to early parsing?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.
Also: is the Low Variable set to early parsing? 
This was really helpful.